# transifex Error cannot import name six

Tags: python, django, six-python

I download and install the [transifex](https://github.com/jakul/python-transifex) with several steps but I always get `Error cannot import name six`:

```
apt-get install python-dev

apt-get install gcc make

install python python-setuptools python-imaging

easy_install transifex

easy_install pip

pip install django-celery
```

How can I run the transifex without error?

Comment: Please, describe how did you install `transifex`. Btw, have you tried to install six? `pip install six`.

Comment: `six` is a pure python module.  It should be pretty trivial to install.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev -- I assume that `transifex` was installed via the `easy_install` command from setuptools...

Comment: pip install six 

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/six-1.3.0-py2.6.egg
Cleaning up...

Comment: I tried easy_install transifex  then I use http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/howto-install-transifex-with-mysql-on-debian-lenny/ and  http://help.transifex.com/server/install.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, there were some unneeded libraries floating around that got in the way, and `sudo apt autoremove` fixed it. I was also missing `urllib3.exceptions`, which I installed with `pip install urllib3`.